# Getting Node.js up and running - DB connection errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm super new to Node.js, so this is probably a really basic question, but what is happening when the console is telling me

```
Error: unable to connect to database at mongodb://localhost/realjoet-me-development
```

I'm running my environment using swig, sass, node, express, gulp, nodemon and yeoman.

I have my DB set up on Heroku with a MongoLab add-on.

What could be causing this error that then causes my app to crash so I can't view it on my localhost??

What more do you need to know to better understand my situation??

Here's the entire console log

```
➜  realjoet.me git:(master) ✗ gulp
[06:50:13] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/realjoet.me/gulpfile.js
[06:50:13] Starting 'sass'...
[06:50:13] Starting 'develop'...
[06:50:13] Finished 'develop' after 6.51 ms
[06:50:13] Starting 'watch'...
[06:50:13] Finished 'watch' after 9.09 ms
[06:50:13] [nodemon] 1.8.0
[06:50:13] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[06:50:13] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[06:50:13] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[06:50:13] /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/public/css/style.css reloaded.
[06:50:13] Finished 'sass' after 243 ms
[06:50:13] Starting 'default'...
[06:50:13] Finished 'default' after 4.09 μs
[06:50:14] /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me reloaded.
Express server listening on port 3000
/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^
Error: unable to connect to database at mongodb://localhost/realjoet-me-development
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/app.js:11:9)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:107:17)
at NativeConnection.Connection.error (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:425:8)
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:452:14
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:52:21
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:226:14
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:233:9)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:263:68)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:77:12)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:121:49)
[06:50:14] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[06:50:27] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[06:50:27] [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[06:50:28] /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me reloaded.
Express server listening on port 3000
/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:235
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^
Error: unable to connect to database at mongodb://localhost/realjoet-me-development
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/app.js:11:9)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:107:17)
at NativeConnection.Connection.error (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:425:8)
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:452:14
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:52:21
at /Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:226:14
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:233:9)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:263:68)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:77:12)
at g (events.js:199:16)
at emit (events.js:110:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/realjoet/Sites/realjoet.me/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:121:49)
[06:50:28] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Do you have a working Internet connection? Is the access blocked by firewall? Do you have a DB accessible on the address you are trying to access?

Comment: @Jayram No to the first two but I'm not sure on the last.. that's what I'm confused about, I suppose. I grabbed this Node.js template from a buddy of mine that created a premade env (Check out repo here: https://github.com/corbanb/bdw-blog) and I'm not sure exactly how it's connected/how I would check out that third issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a mongodb uri from mongolab for your database that you need to use in your application. Check out this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#connecting-to-existing-mongolab-deployments-from-heroku

And then you'll need to point the mongodb ORM that you're using in the Node.js application to that mongodb uri.

Best.

Comment: So I need to create a route router.js file that points to the DB, is that what you're saying??

Comment: Great link by the way, very helpful!

Comment: How are you connecting to your mongodb now?

Comment: I don't think I am, currently. I don't have a route for it at the moment. Working on figuring out how to connect to my MongoLab DB I connected on my Heroku as an add-on.

Comment: Figured it out, just didn't know anything about the URI or how to set up a dev envt. That link got me fixed up!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just needed to find my MongoDB URI and replace the DB source path in my config.js file.

Thanks to everyone that helped. That link was clutch, @R.A. Lucas!

Link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#connecting-to-existing-mongolab-deployments-from-heroku